# Converting XML attributes into a List as for using parameters into a function in Python

Tags: python, xml, function, wsdl, zeep

I have an `xml` query to get data from a wsdl request like this;

```
<prod:insert>

   <key> my_key </Key>
   <signature> my_signature </signature>
   <variable>
      <code> my_code </code>
      <title> my_title </title>
   </variable>

</prod:insert>
```

To send this query, I am basically using `list` in `python`.

```
import zeep

sent_to_api =["my_key","my_signature",["my_code","my_title"]]

my_data = client.service.service_name(*sent_to_api)
```

As it can be seen the `python` codes above, I'am just using the values inside the tags and put them into the `list`. And these codes are working fine! So I can get the data from the source.

However, when it comes to get a more complicated `xml` query which are including attributes, I haven't achieved to pass the values into the function.

The `xml` codes with `attributes` which I want to send are as below;

```
<prod:insert>
   <key> my_key </key>
   <signature> my_signature </signature>
   <variable>
      <code> my_code </code>
      <title> my_title </title>
      <specs>
         <spec name="X" value="15" />
         <spec name="Y" value="10.0T" />
      </specs>
   </variable>
</prod:insert>
```

I tried " *list inside list* ", " *dict inside list* ", " *tupple inside list* " etc. But I couldn't find a solution.

How can I put those attributes into the list to be used as the parameters inside the function?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

> ... but I couldn't find a solution

This is because there isn't a simple one.

A simple nested list cannot represent a complete XML document that uses more than one "axis" (for a loose definition of "axis").  In the first example you use only the parent/child axis, but in the second you use the "attribute" axis as well, meaning your data structure has three dimensions.  This cannot be represented directly as nested lists without some flattening, and including some metadata in the output structure:

```
<prod:insert>
   <key> my_key </key>
   <signature> my_signature </signature>
   <variable>
      <code> my_code </code>
      <title> my_title </title>
      <specs>
         <spec name="X" value="15" />
         <spec name="Y" value="10.0T" />
      </specs>
   </variable>
</prod:insert>
```

Becomes

```
[my_key, my_signature, [my_code, my_title, [ ["X", "15"], ["Y", "10.0T"] ] ]
```

I assume that `<specs>` can contain some unknown number of `<spec>` elements.

This of course presumes that the XML strictly follows a schema ensuring that elements always appear in the same position.

The best solution is to use a combination of nested dicts and lists

```
{ key:my_key, 
  signature:my_signature, 
  [ // variable
    { code: my_code, 
      title:my_title, 
      [ // specs
        { name:X, value:15} 
        { name:Y, value:10.0T}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

There's more than one way to structure this. I elided the names `variable` and `specs` as they didn't add any semantics, but you could make them named objects if you wanted to.

Comment: With respect to your answer, I start from a very basic query to test the accuracy of the setting you offered. XML, which has no child... `<dev:Developer>
   <nick>test_user</nick>
   <password>PW</password>
   <lang>en</lang>
</dev:Developer>`.. To run this, I sent `send_data = {'nick':'test_user',
            'password' :'PW',
            'lang':'en'
            }`...But it does not work! However `['test_user','PW','en']` is still working..

Comment: Additionally, the last codes you wrote .( I mean `{ key:my_key,...` ) are giving syntax error in PYTHON.

Comment: That wasn’t actual code, just an example of how to structure things.

Comment: Thank you for your advices. I am still trying to set and solve. I hope to find a way to handle.